# How to open a new tab in cypress and get back to the previous tab

Tags: javascript, cypress

When i click on a button a new tab is opened and then i do certain actions in it
I need to open the new tab and switch to the previous tab..There is no button to go to the previous tab so i need the two tabs open so that i can switch between them.

I have tried the below:

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
cy.stub(win, 'open', url =>
{
  url = "/#/myurl"
  win.location.href = Cypress.config().baseUrl + url;
   }).as("popup")
})
cy.get('#button').click()
cy.get("@popup").should("be.called")
```

The issue with this code is that it is only opening the new tab and not keeping the other tab open..IS there any way to achieve this.
Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using `cy.go('back')`? That navigate based on the history.

Answer (score 4):

Cypress does not support opening a new tab, it can't handle it, so an alternate way to solve this problem is: If you are using <`a`> tag and it is having `target="_blank"` attribute then you can remove this attribute by using `cy.get('yourLocator').invoke('removeAttr','target').click();` command to resolve this issue. If your new tab is redirecting to the new domain then you can use `cy.origin()`, and for going back you can use `cy.go('back')`for more details about **origin** & **cy.go** visit [cypress.io](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/origin#Using-dynamic-data-in-a-secondary-origin) & [go](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/go#Syntax), I hope this will solve your issue.

```
    cy.origin('https://www.youtube.com/',()=>{
    cy.get('yourlocator').click();
    });
```